# ActionScript 2.0 button if object is visible when clicked to stay visible

Tags: flash, if-statement, actionscript-2

I am making a program and I need assistance. I've tried many things, looked online on many websites. Hope you can help me.

The following url takes you to the [".swf"](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2015/038/0/7/test_by_deco_kun-d8h0tk1.swf).
All the coding is there available for copy/paste.

**So what I want is:**

When I click **sym3 btn**, to ask if **cl_sym1** & **cl_sym2** are visible or invisible to stay that way they are at the time the button is clicked.

example - If the user has **sym3** visible & **cl_sym2** invisible. When they click **sym3 btn**, **cl_sym2** & **cl_sym1** to stay invisible. But if either of **cl_sym2** & **cl_sym1** are visible to stay visible.

**Important Note:** sym1, cl_sym1 will be on top of sym2, cl_sym2 on the final program. Meaning only sym1, cl_sym1 or sym2, cl_sym2 have to be visible.

**Note:** That there will be more than one **sym3 btn**'s in the final program.

**Note2:** This **.swf** is just a simpler example. It is not the actual program.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use AS2? Its a very old language which has been superseded by AS3. You might find it hard to find decent resources for AS2.

Comment: Yeah. I know I should have moved to AS3. But I've started the program in AS2. It's too late to go to AS3 now.

Comment: Could you use more easy-to-understand names and re-explain your problem ?

Comment: are you trying to simulate logic gates? Is your program ready yet?